# What does mean Double Asterisk in gradle? not path

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.play.review/Editor/Dependencies.xml:3
    implementation 'com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:2.1.0' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleUmpDependencies.xml:7
**DEPS**}

// Android Resolver Exclusions Start
android {
  packagingOptions {
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips/*' + '*')
  }
}
// Android Resolver Exclusions End
android {
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
   
}**REPOSITORIES**
**IL_CPP_BUILD_SETUP**
**SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**
**EXTERNAL_SOURCES**
```

I'm writing because I have a question.
extract from unity.
I don't know  what's mean '**' double asterisk?
added grdle script, what is '**bulabula**'

For example, a script like the one below
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

Comment: Those are items that Unity replaces before the build. Most are documented here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/gradle-templates.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This double asterisk is not actually a gradle syntax. In Unity terms it is called [Template variables](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/gradle-templates.html). Not all of them are well documented or documented at all. Unity replaces them to some other lines on building. You can find final gradle files after this replacement in your `/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle` folder. Some of these variables values are generated based on your project settings or other stuff. I do not now way to modify explicit gradle syntax text, that will be replaced, but you always can add things you like after this variables.

For example there is `**PACKAGING_OPTIONS**` template. In my project it adds this lines to final gradle file.

```
    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
        doNotStrip '*/arm64-v8a/*.so'
    }
```

If I want to add some instructions to `packagingOptions` I do not need modify `**PACKAGING_OPTIONS**` template. I just can write code like this:

```
    // ... gradle file ...
    **PACKAGING_OPTIONS**

    packagingOptions {
           pickFirst('Somthing') // for example
    }
```

In this case final gradle-file will be:

```
    // ... gradle file ...
    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
        doNotStrip '*/arm64-v8a/*.so'
    }

 
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst('Something')
    }
```

And gradle handle this well. It will work just like it would be:

```
    // ... gradle file ...
    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
        doNotStrip '*/arm64-v8a/*.so'
        pickFirst('Something')
    }
```